# Connecting to TN3270 Mainframe using VBA

Tags: excel, mainframe, vba

I need to automate a TN3270 mainframe screen using VBA , i am not able to connect to the mainframe using VBA , any chance anyone has automated a TN3270 mainframe emulator using VBA??

Comment: I tossed your title into an internet search If that doesn't get you somewhere after applying some of the suggestions, update your question to show all that you tried, how it didn't work, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: It depends on the Terminal Emulator, some support VBA access; some do not.  Have a look at the documentation for the Terminal Emulator. For complicated tasks, any solution will most likely be unique to the terminal emulator being used.

Comment: Thank you all i googled as suggested by Bill (which BTW was not easy) and found a solution :-) again thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bruce Martin stated, it depends on the Emulator which we are using. I am using the EXTRA! Attachmate which can be automated using Excel VBA using the Extra keyword in the createobject object. Something like:

```
set New=createObject(Extra.system)
```

After connection you can use the `sendkeys`, `getstring`, `putstring` keywords along with the co-ordinates of the screen which is pretty fun and easy.

I have not fully figured this out, but for starters I think it's enough.

Comment: Well Thank you Bill.. I am new to this page :-)